# How can Elric be reborn if Stormbringer trapped his soul?

Tags: elric-saga, eternal-champion, michael-moorcock

Michael Moorcock's Elric is supposed to be one of many incarnations of an "Eternal Champion", yet the Elric book *Stormbringer* ends with the titular sword killing him and absorbing his soul- so how could he be reincarnated?

Comment: Since they're incarnations, not reincarnations, it seems likely that the Eternal Champion phenomenon is decoupled from any single person's soul. So Elric is not reborn, he's destroyed, but another Eternal Champion will inevitably arise who is not related to Elric.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments -- if this is a dupe, VTC as dupe, or else write an answer.